# xp_fileexist with IF EXISTS

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm currently attempting to create a stored procedure that checks to see if a file is there, and if so it then runs some more code, if not. It stops.

So am using `exec master..xp_fileexist @FileName`

This returns

```
File Exists| File is a Directory| Parent Directory Exists
          1|                   0| 1
```

I can't figure out the syntax or set up for putting the stored proc into a `IF EXISTS` statement

```
IF EXISTS (
          exec master..xp_fileexist @FileName

          )

BEGIN 
select 'File is there'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
select 'File is not there'
END
```

The above doesn't work, can anyone put me on the right path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best approach I can think of for this is to use an `OPENROWSET` and populate a temp table with the results of your stored procedure. But tricky with a parameter being passed however this link should get you started in the right direction

http://sqlserverplanet.com/tsql/insert-stored-procedure-results-into-table

Once your table is populated just use a normal `IF EXISTS` query

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like this:

```
declare @result as int
declare @path as nvarchar(50)

--set your path
set @path= 'C:\'

 EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist @path, @result OUTPUT

 if @result=1 
    print 'found'
 else
    print 'not found'
```

Answer (score 1):

`xp_fileexists` always returns a result.

So you don't want to check if the result exists, you want to check the results of the procedure call.

To get the results of a procedure call, you can use the `insert... exec` construct

```
declare @t table (fileexists bit, fileisdirectory bit, parentdirectoryexists bit)
insert @t 
exec master..xp_fileexist 'c:\windows\explorer.exe'

if (exists (select * from @t where fileexists=1))
begin
    select 'file is there'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. navigate to Sql Server Configuration Manager
2. on left panel go to SQL Server Services
3. select your own instance(`MyPc\Sqlexpress`)
4. enter account name and username and password

After you've done this check your code again.  It should be working.